# EGit Pull, Push, Merge, not working

Tags: eclipse, merge, push, egit, jgit

After pulling updates to a project I am working on with some partners, Eclipse Git is not allowing me to continue pushing, pulling or merging.

When I last pulled the updates, there were conflicts in the `web.xml`, so I deleted the conflicting text and saved just the correct one. However, Eclipse is continuing to show the double-diamond icon on the `web.xml` file, indicating there are conflicts. When I try to pull again, I get:

```
Cannot pull into a repository with state: MERGING
org.eclipse.jgit.api.errors.WrongRepositoryStateException
```

[image: Git State Merging]

When I try to push my own commit I get

[image: Git Push Commit Error Screenshot]

This is what it looks like in the History view

[image: Git History]

How do I solve these issues and sucessfully push my commit?

Comment: You likely need to resolve the merge first by adding it to the index and completing the pull by committing the merged state.

Answer (score 0):

First reset your HEAD from the merge state to previous commit

Add files to Index

Fetch, Pull from the Origin

Merge the branch, Resolve if any conflicts

Commit and Push the Merge

Comment: I don't remember what I did to move on from this, and I'm not able to test your answer, so I'll wait for someone else who has the same problem to provide some feedback